# Mediation study help

Tags: linear-algebra, mediation

I have a simple order of operations question with sum products, I want to calculate the natural direct effect (NDE) for x and x prime on data similar to those below. My simple question is:

Do I first calculate the delta of x and x prime creating a new feature called delta_x, then multiply this by the p_of_product and sum that result or do I do this in some other order? Or do I sum `med_purchases_xprime` `med_purchases_x` and `p_of_product` individually before multiplying across?

I have treated the expected values as the median value of purchases under the 2 conditions, x and x prime, and z is equal to the products, y is the expected value for both conditions (calculated as median value).

I have included usable R code, below, if it helps

$$
NDE_{x,x′}(Y)\ = \Sigma_z \ [E(Y|x′,z)−E(Y|x,z)]P(z|x)
$$

```
   product med_purchases_xprime med_purchases_x p_of_product
1 Product1                    3               5          0.2
2 Product2                    5               1          0.4
3 Product3                    7               2          0.6
4 Product4                    2               4          0.4
5 Product5                    3               3          0.3
```

Dummy sample data

````
# Create a dataframe with the specified columns
df <- data.frame(
  product = c("Product1", "Product2", "Product3", "Product4", "Product5"),
  med_purchases_xprime = c(3, 5, 7, 2, 3),
  med_purchases_x = c(5, 1, 2, 4, 3),
  p_of_product = c(0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.4, 0.3)
)

```
````

Comment: Welcome to cv, I_like_insights ! I was just wondering how you chose the tags for your post - they seem not related to your question. One important function of the tags are to attract people who know about the topic to your question, and make them answer :-) There is for example a tag `mediation` that you may want to add to your question, while `sigma-algebra` and `sum` rather signal to some statisticians to stay clear from that question. :-) I'll add mediation, and you can revert back if you prefer.

Comment: Great help! Thank you so much.